# Spring Data JPA 3.0.7 interface query ignoring @Convert annotation for a boolean mapping to a string column

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm upgrading an app from Spring Boot 2.5, spring data jpa 2.6.4, Hibernate 5.5.7
to Spring Boot 3.0.7, spring data jpa 3.0.7, Hibernate 6.1.7

I could previous use a @Convert on a boolean column that was stored as CHAR(1), and use SpringDataJPA interface queries like....
`findBy.....AndActiveIsTrue`

The app originally used Oracle when it didn't support boolean columns.  So I've been using a @Convert annotation

```
    @Column(name = "active", nullable = false)
    @Convert(converter = BooleanToStringConverter.class)
    private boolean active = false;
```

After upgrading, the SQL that is generated is not
`WHERE active = 'Y'` it is just `WHERE active`

I looked in the release notes, and didn't see anything related, but I could've missed it.

Any ideas what I may be missing to get it to correctly generate using the annotation again?